# Authenticate a user from a MAUI app against the local Microsoft Identity in the ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, maui, asp.net-core-identity, microsoft-identity-platform, asp.net-core-8

I have created a website with ASP.NET 8.0 Core. In this web application, I added `Microsoft Identity` and I added Microsoft and Google as external providers. So, a user can register or login with the local credentials or one of the external providers.

On the website, the authentication is working. Now, I want to extend the registration and the login from the MAUI application.

My idea is to create a few APIs for the authentication and in particular:

- a login endpoint that receives username and password
- a registration endpoint with all the basic details of the user (name, surname, email and password)

Is this a correct approach or best practice?

The other issue I'm thinking about is the authentication with the external providers. How can I manage the authentication from the app for Microsoft and Google and verify that the user exists in the web application?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android

Comment: I saw that but the solution is not working with Windows, plus, it doesn't check the user with the user presents in the Microsoft Identity